# Issue in adding Annotation SwaggerDefinition at class level

Tags: inria-spoon

I am new to spoon library for transformation of java source. Trying to use it to transform existing REST services. Requirement is to add io.swagger.annotations.SwaggerDefinition annotation at class level, e.g.:

```
 @SwaggerDefinition(
        tags = {
            @Tag(
                  name = "api name", description = "api description"
                )
               }
 )
```

The issue being faced is that when I am adding the annotation, its being added as:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(
        tags = 
            @Tag(
                  name = "api name", description = "api description"
                )                   
 )
```

*Note*: The missing curly braces '{' and matching closing brace '}'

Following are the functions that are being used:

```
private CtAnnotation createSwaggerDefinitionAnnotation(CtClass<?> ctClass) throws JSONException {

        CtAnnotation tagAnnotation = createTagAnnotation(ctClass);

        CtAnnotation swaggerDefAnnotation = getFactory().Core().createAnnotation();
        CtTypeReference<Object> ref = getFactory().Core().createTypeReference();
        ref.setSimpleName("SwaggerDefinition");

        CtPackageReference refPackage = getFactory().Core().createPackageReference();
        refPackage.setSimpleName("io.swagger.annotations");
        ref.setPackage(refPackage);
        swaggerDefAnnotation.setAnnotationType(ref);

        swaggerDefAnnotation.addValue("tags", tagAnnotation); // TODO: The tag should be wrapped in curly braces

        return swaggerDefAnnotation;
    }

private CtAnnotation createTagAnnotation(CtClass<?> ctClass) {

        String className = ctClass.getQualifiedName();

        CtAnnotation tagAnnotation = getFactory().Core().createAnnotation();
        CtTypeReference<Object> ref = getFactory().Core().createTypeReference();
        ref.setSimpleName("Tag");

        CtPackageReference refPackage = getFactory().Core().createPackageReference();
        refPackage.setSimpleName("io.swagger.annotations");
        ref.setPackage(refPackage);
        tagAnnotation.setAnnotationType(ref);

        tagAnnotation.addValue("name", getSwaggerDefinitionTagName(className));
        tagAnnotation.addValue("description", getSwaggerDefinitionTagDescription(className));
        return tagAnnotation;
    }
```

Can someone identify the missing piece. I am NOT able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the brace around the values, you need to create a CtNewArray that contains the values of your annotation.

```
private CtAnnotation createSwaggerDefinitionAnnotation(CtClass<?> ctClass) {

    CtAnnotation tagAnnotation = createTagAnnotation(ctClass);

    CtAnnotation swaggerDefAnnotation = getFactory().Core().createAnnotation();
    CtTypeReference<Object> ref = getFactory().Core().createTypeReference();
    ref.setSimpleName("SwaggerDefinition");

    CtPackageReference refPackage = getFactory().Core().createPackageReference();
    refPackage.setSimpleName("io.swagger.annotations");
    ref.setPackage(refPackage);
    swaggerDefAnnotation.setAnnotationType(ref);

    CtNewArray<Object> arrayValue = getFactory().Core().createNewArray();
    arrayValue.addElement(tagAnnotation);
    swaggerDefAnnotation.addValue("tags", arrayValue);

    return swaggerDefAnnotation;
}
```

ouput:

```
@io.swagger.annotations.SwaggerDefinition(
tags = { 
    @io.swagger.annotations.Tag(
           description = "description", name = "name") 
})
```